# How to fix IE error when save photo edited with Konva?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, konvajs

I am trying to make a photo editor, do add some squares on images with Konva JS. I was able to get things done for all the browsers, but unfortunately IE cannot figure out. When I'm trying to save edited image, seems like it ignore everything from Konva (the squares) and more than that is stretching the image. I've asked a Konva moderator if has support for IE, and he told me that the library has compatibility with IE.

The app is made in Laravel and the request for saving is sent in controller by Ajax

Javascript:

```
 function saveInCanvas () {
            destroyTransformer();
            destroyPreview();
            html2canvas(element, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                    getCanvas = canvas;
                    var keyFrameId = $('#current-frame').attr('attr');
                    destroyTransformer();

                    dataURL = getCanvas.toDataURL();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ route('save_debrand') }}",
                        data: {
                            survey_id: {{ $survey->id }},
                            imgBase64: dataURL,
                            keyFrameId: keyFrameId,
                            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        },
                        success: function(response){
                            debrandingPreviousNextImage("imageSaved");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };
```

Controller:

```
public function ajxSaveEdited(Request $request){

    $image    = Image::make($request->get('imgBase64'));
    $filename = uniqid().'.jpg' ;
    $file     = public_path('storage/surveys/'.$filename);
    $image->save($file);
```

}

Does IE has something particular for getting image from canvas?
Thank you!

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: It's about IE 11.

Comment: Why do you need `html2canvas` here? Do you save more than just canvas? Other DOM elements?

Comment: Yes I do, it is the image that has to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, I just applied an z-index for the canvas which is dynamically appended to the div (this is the way Konva creates canvas)